# Check decimal and total length of number

Tags: c#, regex

Using [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hU5aP0/1), I can check if it is decimal or not

```
^\d*\.?\d*$
```

But what I want to control is total length of those digit.

```
(^\d*\.?\d*$){1,10}
```

But I still cannot control it.

After 2 days later, my final [solution](https://regex101.com/r/hU5aP0/4) is

```
(?=^\d*\.?\d*$)^.{1,10}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Ht2E8amMetO3AJY4)

Comment: Remove the `*` after `\d`.

Comment: What engine/language are you using ? This won't be easy in a simple regex with some engines.

Comment: I am using C# @DenysSéguret

Comment: What do you mean by "total length"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
^(?!.{10})\d*\.?\d*$
```

This will check the whole number isn't more than 10 characters.

If you want to check the whole number isn't more than 10 *digits* (not counting the dot), you may use

```
^((?!.{11})\d*\.\d*|(?!.{10})\d*)$
```

Comment: Seguret, +1 vote for your great suggestion, It help me a lot.But I still have question, If I want to limit 10 digit, I have to make `^(?!.{11})\d*\.?\d*$`, if i want 11 digit limitation, I have to make `..{12}..`. So is there any other way? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
(^\d*\.?\d*$){1,10}
    ↑     ↑
```

The `*` means, zero or more. So your regex means "zero or more times, from 1 to 10 times", so `{1,10}` in this case is redundant. You need to remove `*` or apply `{1,10}` only to parts that doesn't have it.

For example, you can change your regex to:

```
^\d*(\.?\d{0,10})$
```

This matches numbers that has up to 10 digits after the dot. If you want to match a float number that has 10 digits in total, you can use negative lookahead (as @DenysSéguret already mentioned in his answer +1):

```
(?!.{10})\d*\.?\d*
```

It matches `\d*\.?\d*$` only if it its length < 10 (including the dot).